# Getting Error when connection scott schema from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting below error when ever trying to connect DB from sql developer.

[image]

> Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with
>   the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know
>   of service requested in connect descriptor

But successfully connect from command prompt.

I have set the path in environment variable correctly.

Can you please help me with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Try using sid. I don't think capitalization matters but I always use ORCL in caps.

Comment: The command line uses a tnsnames entry (usually).  Do you have localhost identified as your host in your tnsnames entry?